JPQL SELECT: how replace the original value of property
I need to replace the original value of a property named status within my Order object with some calculated value. The problem is that when I try to do this, like we do normally in SQL, I get this error:
The identification variable 'status' cannot be declared more than once.
this is my query:
SELECT o.orderDate,
CASE WHEN (o.status = 'CANCELLED') THEN 'SUBSTITUTED' ELSE o.status END AS status
FROM Order o

So my Order object has status property, I just want to manipulate the value. But JPQL thinks I am declaring the variable more than once! Most probably because there are both the original status and a custom status that I am declaring as in-line. But my confusion is that I never tried to select o.status just used in in calculation!
I am using EclipseLink! Is there a way to achieve this? Please note that I need to do this value replacement only in query level, and not as an annotation on the property level in the class. Thanks.
Some more stack trace:
####2024-09-19T11:34:43,169 ThreadId:67  ERROR entity.jpa.EclipseLinkJpqlMetaDataExtractor - Exception building database query  <LogContext:none> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT o.orderDate,
    CASE WHEN (o.status = 'CANCELLED') THEN 'SUBSTITUTED' ELSE o.status END AS status
    FROM Order o]. 
[2625, 2631] The identification variable 'status' cannot be declared more than once.
[1301, 1307] The identification variable 'status' cannot be declared more than once.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:157) ~[eclipselink.jar:2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:349) ~[eclipselink.jar:2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:280) ~[eclipselink.jar:2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:165) ~[eclipselink.jar:2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142) ~[eclipselink.jar:2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f]


Is the error coming from EclipseLink or the database? Not many really define variables in the returned values for raw data in apps I've seen or supported.

From EclipseLink

Show the full exception stack, and the version of EclipseLink you are using

@Chris I added some stack trace, and my EclipseLink version is 2.7.6

Does it work if you use something other than 'as status' or just remove it outright?

Yes, currently I did that, named it statusfilterable. but it has implications for me, as I had to make changes to other places, and still status is there which is a mess.

I don't quite understand - it worked? What are the implications - most results i've seen use positional parameter, or have labels like this tightly integrated in the query. Are you maybe trying to have Spring build a projection object from this, where you could just use 'select new myprojectObject(o.orderDate, case... ) from ..' instead?
Otherwise, it looks like a bug in the parser used. EclipseLink allows switching the parser, but the 'other' one might give you more trouble.

Actually it was only a workaround, meanwhile I am looking for actual solution. So still I want to manipulate the original value but use the same name of the property (status). But maybe it is a bug in EclipseLink.
